# Persisting Spring Cloud Gateway Routes in Database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am currently using the spring cloud gateway project to build simple api gateway, the plan was to persist the route in mongodb, then refresh, so that the new route can be available. I have done something simple like this to get my route from mongo.

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
    List<CreateAPIRequest> apiRequestList = repository.findAll();
    RouteLocatorBuilder.Builder routeLocator = builder.routes();
    for (CreateAPIRequest request: apiRequestList) {
        routeLocator
        .route(r-> {
              r.path("/"+request.getProxy().getListenPath())
             .filters(f->f.stripPrefix(1))
             .uri(request.getProxy().getTargetUrl()) 
        });
    }
    return routeLocator.build();
}
```

I was able to create new route in the db, but I am unable to refresh on the fly.

I need to understand how to refresh the routes on the fly.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you wish to update the routes dynamically send a RefreshRoutesEvent. The following component implements the event sending functionality.

```
@Component
public class GatewayRoutesRefresher implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware {

    ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
        publisher = applicationEventPublisher;
    }

    public void refreshRoutes() {
        publisher.publishEvent(new RefreshRoutesEvent(this));
    }
}
```

Here is a sample showing how to use the component above:

```
@Autowired
GatewayRoutesRefresher gatewayRoutesRefresher;
...
public void buildRoutes() {
    // build your routes basing on your db entries then refresh the routes in gateway
    ...
    gatewayRoutesRefresher.refreshRoutes();
}
```

You can find a more complete picture of the concept by looking into the following project code: https://github.com/botorabi/HomieCenter

Answer (score 5):

SCG(Spring Cloud Gateway) has been provided `RouteDefinitionRepository`, you can write your own RouteDefinitionRepository, and implements `RouteDefinitionRepository` to override `getRouteDefinitions` method.

You can refer to this class: `InMemoryRouteDefinitionRepository`

For example:

```
@Service
public class MongodbDefinitionRepository implements RouteDefinitionRepository {

    @Autowired
    private RouteConfigDao routeConfigDao;

    @Override
    public Flux<RouteDefinition> getRouteDefinitions() {
        // todo 
        List<RouteDefinition> routeConfigs = routeConfigDao.findAll();
        return Flux.fromIterable(routeConfigs);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> save(Mono<RouteDefinition> route) {
        return route.flatMap(routeDefinition -> {
            // todo 
            return Mono.empty();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> delete(Mono<String> routeId) {
        return routeId.flatMap(id -> {
            // todo 
            int delete = routeConfigDao.delete(routeId);
            if (delete > 0) {
                return Mono.empty();
            }
            return Mono.defer(() -> Mono.error(new Exception("delete route definition error, routeId:" + routeId)));
        });
    }
}
```

**How to refresh the routes on the fly**

1. Enable actuator

place this in your `application.yml`

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: gateway
```

POST http://ip:port/actuator/gateway/refresh

2. Publish RefreshRoutesEvent

```
@Service
public class MyPublishBiz implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware {
    protected ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public Mono<Void> refresh() {
        this.publisher.publishEvent(new RefreshRoutesEvent(this));
        return Mono.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, may I ask you how to add RouteConfigDao in my class? It is not a type from SCG, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I went quickly to the repo and the open issues.

And it seems that at the moment the only way to refresh the routes is from Actuator via:

```
/actuator/gateway/refresh
```

You can check the discussion here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/43

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) for persisting your route definitions instead of mongo. Then a simple POST call to the actuator's refresh will reload your route definitions on the fly.